# Kant's Transcendental Apperception and al-`Ilm al-Huduri

Tags: epistemology, kant, islamic-philosophy

What is transcendental apperception in Kant's Philosophy? Is it an instance of knowledge-by-presence (al-`Ilm al-Huduri) in Islamic philosophy (especially Mulla Sadra's al-Hikmah al-Muta`aliyyah)?

Comment: I'm not sure that Kant quite understood the idea of knowledge by identity or presence. Had he done so he would have been less certain that the thing-in-itself is not knowable. I may be doing him an injustice, but apperception is mind's study of itself and while this is important it is not quite the way to get beyond Mind to Identity and 'knowledge by presence'. It seems to me Kant almost recreated the perennial philosophy but had to give up because he did not have the idea of nonduality in his tool-kit.

Comment: The ["transcendental unity of apperception"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-mind/#3.3) is notoriously obscure in Kant, but it is quite clear that it is not knowledge of anything, by presence or otherwise. It is a kind of unifying thread stringing cognitions together and making them into cognitions of a single "self", which, Kant claims, is a condition of the possibility of knowledge. But he derives its existence from an abstract transcendental argument with external knowledge for premises, not from some feels or presences we may or may not experience internally.

Answer (score 2):

Transcendental apperception is a fundamental concept in Immanuel Kant's critical philosophy. In his seminal work, "Critique of Pure Reason," Kant describes transcendental apperception as the self-consciousness that is the foundation of our experience of an objective world (Kant, 1781/1787). It is the self-awareness that accompanies all our experiences and unifies them into a coherent whole. As such, it's the basis for our experience of the self and the world.

Kant says: "The I think must be able to accompany all my representations; for otherwise, something would be represented in me that could not be thought at all, which is as much as to say that the representation would either be impossible or else at least would be nothing for me." (Kant, "Critique of Pure Reason," A 107)

Knowledge-by-presence (al-Ilm al-Huduri), as defined in Islamic philosophy, particularly in the work of Mulla Sadra's al-Hikmah al-Mutaaliyyah (The Transcendent Theosophy), is a type of knowledge that is non-discursive and immediate. It's an intuition, or direct apprehension, of the truth or reality, typically associated with mystical or religious experiences (Corbin, 1971; Nasr, 2006).

While there are some parallels between Kant's transcendental apperception and Mulla Sadra's knowledge-by-presence, the two concepts are not precisely equivalent. The central distinction lies in the fact that Kant's concept is primarily epistemological, pertaining to the conditions of possible experience, while Sadra's concept is both epistemological and ontological, referring not only to the conditions of knowledge but also to the nature of being and reality.

Moreover, Kant's transcendental apperception is a universal feature of human cognition, while Sadra's knowledge-by-presence is typically regarded as a form of knowledge that is attained only in special circumstances or states of consciousness (such as mystical or religious experiences).

In conclusion, while there are similarities between the two concepts, they are not identical and serve different purposes within their respective philosophical systems.

References:

Kant, Immanuel. Critique of Pure Reason. Translated by Paul Guyer and Allen W. Wood, Cambridge University Press, 1998.

Corbin, Henry. Creative Imagination in the Ṣūfism of Ibn ‘Arabī. Translated by Ralph Manheim, Princeton University Press, 1971.

Nasr, Seyyed Hossein. The Garden of Truth: The Vision and Promise of Sufism, Islam's Mystical Tradition. HarperOne, 2006.